# Algebraic system with tan and arctan

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve the system $\arctan {x}=\tan {y}+\tan{z},\arctan {y}=\tan {x}+\tan{z},\arctan {z}=\tan {x}+\tan{y}$, without success. My basic idea is that $f(y,z)=\tan {y}+\tan{z}$ is a periodic function (with period $\pi $), since $g(x)=\arctan {x}$ is a non periodic function. On the other hand, $x=y=z=0$ is a solution. I stuck.

Comment: One possibility is that $x=y=z$, as you suggested.

Look for more solutions to $\arctan(x)=2\tan(x)$

If you think about it, this *should* have infinite solutions, as the graph of $\arctan(x)$ intersects $2\tan(x)$ approximately every $π$ units.

On Wolfram, there aren't particularly clean solutions, though.

Comment: is there any solution?